# Why does uniprot sometimes not label single-pass transmembrane proteins as "anchors"?

Tags: bioinformatics, cell-membrane, database

Currently, section 3a) of [unitprot `TRANSMEM` reference page](http://www.uniprot.org/help/transmem) divides single-pass transmembrane proteins into 4 types: `I, II, III, IV`. `I` is not explicitly labelled as an "anchor" whereas the others are. What criteria need to be made for a single-pass protein ***not*** to be classed as an anchor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A membrane anchor is close to the end (N-terminus or C-terminus) of a protein. For "Single-pass type I membrane proteins" the transmembrane region is not necessarily close to N- or C-terminus, which is why single-pass type I membrane domain are not labeled as anchors.

Instead, relevant entries usually have a signal peptide annotated.

Note that we have replaced the example for single-pass type I membrane protein by http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P14778#subcellular_location which is more relevant (the modified version of the documentation will be available with release 2016_01).